# jQuery .append() to add required class to form elements

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like my HTML5 form to get an asterisk ('*') for a required field - I can add `required` as an attribute but the rest of the form output is a little cumbersome, due to the software we use.

I've got the following jQuery working, which looks for an attribute of `required` and then appends a `<span>` element.

```
$('*[required]').prev().append('<span class="required">*</span>');
```

I'm not experienced with jQuery so is this an efficient enough way to target a form with, say, 10 required elements? Or could it be improved, eg, is `.appendTo()` or `.insertAfter()` more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to improve using `.before()`:

```
$(':input[required]').before('<span class="required">*</span>');
```

Comment: `.each` is not required.

Comment: Oh yeah i got this now.

Comment: Thanks, this is neater than my example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your code is working and you are pondering:

> so is this an efficient enough way to target a form with, say, 10
>   required elements?

`*` is very in-efficient selector; it matches everything. This means, for example, if your DOM has 1000 elements, the browser has to check all of them for the presence of required attribute. Be specific when possible:

```
$("input[required], select[required], textarea[required]")
```

> Or could it be improved, e.g. .appendTo() or .insertAfter() more
>   appropriate?

It depends on where the `*` is supposed to go. So use the function that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for giving specific example of efficient selecting

Answer (score 0):

Its always expensive to manipulate the dom, but your method does do the trick. but I would do this with css selector, because technically it is a visual thing. If you are supporting older browser your method is fine. Here is a more simplified version

Just an example:

```
$('[required]').wrap('<span class="required">*</span>');
```

This will wrap the input in a span, but you can also wrap your prev element.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to keep the input 'clean', so just need to add before it...if the forms software produced accurate `<label><input>` pairs, this would have been a lot easier!